# forge.facebook.logout() not clearing token

Tags: facebook, trigger.io

Receiving "Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session". 
I would like to clear any tokens and reauthorize/re-login but forge.facebook.logout() is not working. Any solutions?

Comment: I think it might be FB as I am having a similar issue with Trigger and Singly.

Comment: I have the same issue, forge.facebook.logout() does not appear to do anything.

Comment: Here's a forge log clearly showing the access token does not get refreshed: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=UXSf81bq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to debug information provided by Brad Dwyer we narrowed down the issue to the interaction between the Facebook module and the iOS 6 accounts framework.

The problem is fixed in our [v1.4.46 platform version](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/release_notes.html)